# QQuickImageProvider class error

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I wanted to migrate QPixmap from c ++ to qml.
I created a class with the parent QQucikImageProvider

```
class test : public QQuickImageProvider
{

Q_OBJECT
public:
    test():QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Pixmap)
    {

}
QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString & id, QSize * size, const QSize & requestedSize)
{
    int width = 100;
    int height = 50;

    if (size)
        *size = QSize(width, height);
    QPixmap pixmap(requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
                   requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height);
    pixmap.fill(QColor(id).rgba());

    return pixmap;
}

};
```

And declared it in the main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
VK::test *imgProv = new VK::test();
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImageProvider("myprovider",imgProv);
...
}
```

But at compilation I received the following errors:

```
moc_api.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19QQuickImageProvider11qt_metacastEPKc'

moc_api.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19QQuickImageProvider11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv'

moc_api.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19QQuickImageProvider16staticMetaObjectE'
```

Comment: try remove `Q_OBJECT` macro

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Mohammad Kanan,It did not help